# How to cook fish bones(ideally without oil)?

Tags: fish, bones

I'm wanting to eat fish bones.  What is the best way to cook them?  I imagine it is deep frying if you want quick though it's messy with oil.

I had another thought that I could just wrap them in foil paper, heat them on a pan, turn over etc.  Would this work or might this method introduce any other problems e.g. bones burn, foil sticks to pan etc?

Can the bones be heated on pan without foil paper or oil, might this introduce any problems?

Please note the question is asking about cooking fish bones only i.e. flesh already removed.

Comment: What kind of fish bones?  You do realize that lots of people go to the emergency room when they accidentally eat fish bones, right?

Comment: is there a reason why "inside a fish, while cooking the fish" is not an option? Please edit your question to explain.

Comment: @JohnFeltz It could be any type.  In worst case I think most bones can be softened by frying.  I believe swallowed fish bones only cause problems when they haven't been softened enough for consumption i.e. soft enough that they can be broken\crunched down into smaller pieces.

Answer (score 2):

If they are the bones of fatty, oily fish, the grilling would work, assuming there are still some scraps of meat/fat attached. This will achieve a crunchy texture. Your suggestion of cooking the fish in a pan, wrapped in foil, might also achieve similar results (again use an oily fish).

You could also simmer them in some sort of flavoured broth until they are very soft - I know of a few southeast asian recipes for fish that are slow-cooked in a salty broth for a very long time until the bones are the same texture as the meat and the fish can be eaten whole.

Frying is, in my eyes, the best option for taste and texture - it can be done in relatively little oil, and avoiding too much mess

Comment: i want to avoid ingesting fat\oil hence ideally without oil, in case of frying i'm worried the bones absorb fat\oil?  do they absorb fat\oil?   what if i fry then rinse thoroughly will that remove all oil, or perhaps frying then boiling the water out will achieve desired result?

Comment: @JamesWilson If you fry something properly, it should have minimal oil absorption after you let it cool/drip-dry. And... you do realize there's plenty of oil in the fish you presumably ate to get these bones?

Comment: @SnakeDoc yes however when I usually cook soup or eat raw.  I find that when oil is fried, grilled etc, perhaps due to higher temps I do not do so well on the oil, hence cooking soup, seperating and trying to soften bones.